# "Gram-Schmidt"-like decomposition method for creating independent variables.

Tags: probability-theory, independence

Considering $X$ and $Y$ two variables "unlinked", i.e there is no deterministic $f$ function so that $Y  = f(X)$, is there any theorem ensuring existence/characterization of some $g, h$ functions so that $Y = g(X,Y) + h(X)$, with $g(X,Y)$ and $h(X)$ independants ?

The motivation is the following :

Let's suppose that I am trying to estimate
$$Y = X + T$$
with $T$ a variable vaguely correlated with $X$, i.e. not independant but not "linked" to $X$. I would like to separate T in two parts, one, $f(X)$ "strongly linked" to $X$ and the other one $T - f(X)$ independent from $X$ :

Comment: Trivial solution: take $g$ to be constant. Any constant is trivially independent of any other random variable.

Comment: Ok, right, I added some hypothesis in my question, and some motivation also

Comment: Not quite what you are looking for, but perhaps interesting: define $f(X)=E[Y-X|X]$, then $T-f(X)$ is uncorrelated with $X$.

Comment: In the special case that $X,Y$ are jointly normal, uncorrelatedness is equivalent to independence.